# Length of bicycle frame according to the graph

Tags: physics, recreational-mathematics

Problem reads:

> Aditya is riding a bicycle on a road filled with mud patches. When it is passing through one of those patch, one of the wheels of bicycle traces part of curve $y=\sin (x)$ and the other wheel traces curve with a vertical inflection point as shown in the figure.
> To remove the possible effects due to the bicycle's geometry, wheel size and its tilting, take the bicycle to have vanishingly thin tires with its front axle always positioned dircetly below a vertical headset. Also, assume that its both wheels were in a mud patch when the inflection point is traversed.Determine the distance $\ell$ between its axles.

What I considered was at point of inflection the bike tyres would be in a straightline and tangential to the bottom curve which is of forward track but how to find length from it ? (I know one fact that curve of both will be sinusoidal but length part I am not able to understand how to calculate)

[image]

Comment: I do not understand why the second wheel does not follow exactly the same profile with a length $l$ delay?

Comment: Exactly same profile it may/may not it needs to be proven but yeah overall its tangent